# Is it possible to retrieve json from database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, activerecord

I have a rails(5.1) application with postgres(9.6) as a DB. In one of tables I have jsonb field, and all that I need is just to retrieve this string and send it to client. Why do i need it? Converting to json takes half of total request time

```
my_record.my_json_field # returns hash
my_record.read_attribute(:my_json_field) # also returns hash

# even this hack returns hash
MyRecord.select('my_json_field as temp_field').first[:temp_field]
```

I found two solutions:

```
# proposed by Sergio Tulentsev
# It's a fastest way. you will receive just a hash with fields that you selected
MyRecord.connection.execute(MyRecord.my_scope.to_sql) 

# Another option is to select that data as a text.
# In that case you will receive ActiveRecord objects
MyRecord.select('*', 'my_json_field::text as my_field_as_text').first.my_field_as_text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*porting suggestion from comments, which worked*)

Try `MyRecord.connection.execute_sql` (or what is it called). In all of the examples above you go through the model, which respects your schema and deserializes the hash. You need the raw db connection.